# How to display data from multiple json files at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cookies

I'm dynamically creating the json urls based on what is currently saved inside a browser cookie.

```
var cookie = $.cookie('faved_posts');
```

The contents of that cookie are 123456, 111111, 000001, and so on.

Now I'll need to request the json file for each ID that was saved in that cookie.

I have the following:

```
$.each(cookie, function(i, val){
    $.getJSON('/ajax/posts/'+val+'.json', function(data){
        var html = "<div>" + data.post.headline + "</div>";
        $("#container").html(html);
    });
});
```

I'm able to retrieve all the files
/ajax/posts/123456.json
/ajax/posts/111111.json
/ajax/posts/000001.json

The problem I'm having is I can only render the **data.post.headline** value from only one of the ajax files.

This is what I need outputted in html:

```
<div>headline for 123456</div>
<div>headline for 111111</div>
<div>headline for 000001</div>
```

What is the best way to do something like this? Thanks

Comment: Use `$("#container").append(html)`

Comment: I should probably also use jQuery's $.when they're all .done().

Comment: Wow so simple smacked my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#container").html(html);
```

`.html()` will replace everything that is currently in `#container` which would mean you would only see the `html` from the last execution of the loop. I believe you are looking for [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) instead.